# Resources for understanding Work in Calculus

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, resource-recommendations, definition, calculus

I would like a good resource for an in-depth understanding of Work in calculus, that perhaps most calculus courses don't invest much interest in.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about for "work".  Do you mean the physics concept?

Comment: Yes, work in the physics concept.

Comment: Find an undergraduate physics text aimed at physics majors and engineers. These will all require calculus and cover work thoroughly.

Comment: I'm working on a book of applied calculus for first-year calculus students.  It may have some chapters you are interested in.  I can send you the current work-in-progress if you are interested.

Comment: @johnnyb i would actually appreciate that

Comment: @Lex_i - I added a link to the in-progress book in my profile page.  Just click my name and then click on the book (the last link).  Contact information for me is in the book's introduction.